# app.config configSections custom settings can not find schema information

Tags: c#, schema, app-config

I am just learning about app.config in respect of creating custom sections.  I have that part working, it compiles and gets the information out as required but I get warnings about it could not find the schema information.

I have done a bit of googling and could not find a simple explanation of this situation.

The approach (that seems to make sense to me at the moment) would be to have a schema file for each section within that project.  I understand how to create a schema file, but do not know how I would like this into the project.

Also when it is compiled and deployed to another machine I presume that schema file would need to be copied across as well.

Thanks for any and all help

Jon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try linking the app.config file to the corresponding schema (ussually you can find it on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd) ,to do so  just open the app.config file in visual studio, open the properties window (F4) and put the path above to **schemas**.
Pablo.

Comment: Hi Pablo, 

Thanks for the response I had not noticed that at all. Just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: For VS 2008 (.NET 3.0 & 3.5) you might want to use C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig30.xsd

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for custom configuration sections in Visual Studio 2017.