# How do I make an extension xsd for the web/app.config schema?

Tags: .net, configuration, xsd

How do I make a schema for custom config sections? I tried making one, but when I used it, it said the only expected element was what I had in that schema, and complained about the standard web.config stuff, even though I was still using the normal DotNetConfig.xsd file too.

Comment: I do realize I could probably modify the DotNetConfig.xsd file with the installer, but I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve changing files already on the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378105/how-do-i-get-intellisense-in-app-config-for-a-custom-section

Comment: updated question to make it not a duplicate

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This question I found isn't duplicate, but the solution will solve your problem:

[How to fix Error: "Could not find schema information for the attribute/element" by creating schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/c-sharp-how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute)

#### The trick is to get the "Properties" of the app.config editor, and set the `Schemas` value:

- **Right Click** -> **Properties** anywhere in the XML file editor, or just hit <kbd>F4</kbd> while it is in focus
- In that dialog, add a local or absolute reference to a schema file

My app.config file's properties window/gadget looks like this:

[image: Properties dialog in Visual Studio for the app.config file]

Here's an example I *just* got working (I'm toying around with Ninject and NLog).  The elements and attributes under the `nlog` section show up correctly in Intellisense, and I get squiggly lines if I violate the schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="eventLog" xsi:type="EventLog" log="Application"
              category="TestService" />
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
              layout="${longdate}|${stacktrace}|${message}"
              fileName="${logger}.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="eventLog" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

My schema file is in my project root, right next to app.config, and called `NLog.xsd`.  I simply saved it from here:

- http://nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd

Comment: For some reason, this only got me 98% of the way there. While most compiler warnings went away, I got one new one telling me that the "configuration" element was already defined. After looking at the sample NLog.xsd above, I realized I had more "stuff" in my xsd and once I trimmed it down to only include _my schema_ and not the entire schema of the config file, it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just my environment or something changed in .NET 4.6 (not sure).

**To get intellisense to work with a newly created app.config file...**

**Step 1 : Add a new item App.Config to your solution.**
It will look like this, note the intellisense errors:

[image: AppConfigs]

**Step 2 : Press F4 in the editor to show the Properites page of the XML document:**

My defaults were showing this:

[image: Properties]

**Step 3: Click the elipse at far right of Schemas property above...**

Check the DonNetConfig.xsd, close the window and start typing in

[image: Intellisense]

***No more errors and intellisense works...***

Answer (score -1):

When I tried this, it didn't work. The configuration system assumes that everything is in the default namespace, and chokes if it's not. It's very disappointing.

Comment: Check my new answer.  I got it working (I think we're talking about the same thing here...)