# How do I access and use (add/remove) elements for an custom app.config based on my own schema file?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, app-config

I made my own schema xsd file and load it in my Project Solution like in the post here: [How do I make an extension xsd for the web/app.config schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127315/how-do-i-make-an-extension-xsd-for-the-web-app-config-schema) . It worked like a charm, but now I can't figure it out at the next step how to access the elements and data in the app.config file.

My xds schema file code:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Intellisense" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="generalWorkDir" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="workStations" type="wStation">
<xs:complexType name="wStation">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string">
<xs:element name="workDir" type="xs:string">
<xs:element name="ip" type="xs:string">
<xs:element name="port" type="xs:string">
</xs:sequence>
<xs:/complexType>
```

and the xml file app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<generalWorkDir>c:/Temp/Default</generalWorkDir>
<workStations>
<wStation>
<Name>w1</Name>
<workDir>c:/Temp/w1</workDir>
<ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
<port>8080</port>
</wStation>
</workStations>
```

I mention I work on a Windows Forms application in C#.
Any suggestions? I want to write code in my application in order to access the data from app.config and to add or remove a new workStation.

Comment: Could you please edit your Question and add the Code from the XML and XSD examples to stackoverflow ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your "app.config" isn't even a valid XML file. Also, FYI, app.config is not a database - you don't add and remove elements from it at runtime.

Comment: Like John Saunders already said the purpose of the app.config is something else. With it you can set some options like an ip address your app should connect to.