# Visual Studio intellisense for custom app.config settings?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, configuration-files

I'm working with custom sections in app.config, and would find very useful the same intellisense facilities as exist for the standard settings. I assume I'd have to supply a schema somewhere, but can't work out if/where. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Click on web.config, and then in the properties window you'll see schemas... add yours there.

check this : [How do I get intellisense in app.config for a custom section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378105/how-do-i-get-intellisense-in-app-config-for-a-custom-section/378162#378162)

You can generate a schema too from your c# class using Xsd.exe

example: xsd.exe -t:PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder.dll

try pass in the cs file as file... sure it will work too