# How do I include a web.config custom section schema without having to update each dev machine?

Tags: asp.net, schema, xslt, web-config

I've added a new custom section to the web.config of an application.

I have also created a corresponding schema file for the new section definition.

How do I include the schema reference in the web.config so that any developer editing the section has intellisense enabled when dealing with my new custom config section?

I've seen solutions whereby I include the schema reference within the web.config by having to update the [IDE installation directory]\Packages\schemas\xml location? This works but I want to ensure that any new developer checking out the code on a fresh development machine automatically has the intellisense enabled without having to also update their development machine.

Comment: Hey Brian - did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Hi Dwynne, unfortunately not. I fear that there may not actually be a way to do this other than an installation of schemas on each development machine. Perhaps this becomes a part of the development process in your team rather than an element of the project.

Answer (score 5):

Add your .xsd file as a solution item (or project item).  Visual Studio will automatically use any schema file it finds in a solution.  You may have to restart Visual Studio for it to start working.

You will also need to reference the schema in the section element:

```
<mySection xmlns:name-of-schema>
...
</mySection>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `xmlns="name-of-schema"`?