# Visual Studio .config file <configuration> element warning

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, configuration-files

The default `App.config` file generated by Visual Studio 2013 (with .NET Framework 4.5.1) when a WPF application is created anew, will look something like this.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
> <configuration>
>   <startup> 
>     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
>   </startup> 
> </configuration>
> ```

To this I might add a few elements that define some application settings.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
> <configuration>
>   <startup> 
>     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
>   </startup> 
>   <appSettings>
>     <add key="ConfigureThisThing" value="123" />
>     <add key="SwitchThatThing" value="True" />
>   </appSettings>
> </configuration>
> ```

Upon building, the word `configuration` will become underlined and there will be a warning.

`The 'configuration' element is not declared.`

To get rid of the warning, it seems necessary to define the `<configuration>` attribute `xmlns`.

Is there a default attribute value available somewhere that is very un-constraining and serves simply to get rid of the warning?

There is this [particular stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523996/the-configuration-element-is-not-declared) that suggests

`xmlns="schema URL"`

and while that does get rid of the warning, it does not appear to be a properly formed URL, so it does not seem to make sense. If such an attribute value can be supported or explained or justified, then I will gladly accept it, however there appears to be no information at this [MSDN configuration element description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5x77e536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would justify such an attribute value.

This [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228147%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that the attribute should specify a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `xmlns` attribute does not have to be machine interpreted since it is not required to be used for retrieval. From wikipedia right... now ... is this description.

> A namespace name is a uniform resource identifier (URI). Typically, the URI chosen for the namespace of a given XML vocabulary describes a resource under the control of the author or organization defining the vocabulary, such as a URL for the author's Web server. However, the namespace specification does not require nor suggest that the namespace URI be used to retrieve information; it is simply treated by an XML parser as a string.

Given that, it is easy to provide a non-constraining but accurate URI, such as a URL that is under the control of the person specifying it even if the control serves only to guarantee uniqueness and falls short of offering any automated functionality.