# How to solve "The 'configuration' element is not declared" warning message in C#.net

Tags: c#, app-config, compiler-warnings

This warning generated from my `app.config` file is driving me crazy and I have been searching without getting any real answer as to why this is the case. Here is the code.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523996/the-configuration-element-is-not-declared

Comment: thanks but that question wasn't answered either. I did however looked at and tried the suggestions

Comment: You mean app.config?

Comment: @SteenT Yeah, that what I meant. Must be too tired

Comment: It can't find the schema for some reason.  One thread recommends changing the framework version in properties and then changing it back again (for 2012/13). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element

Answer (score 16):

I fixed the problem for VS2013 and .NET 4.6 targeting projects by editing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Xml\Schemas\catalog.xml.

I modified existing line:

```
<Association extension="config" schema="%InstallRoot%/xml/schemas/%LCID%/dotNetConfig.xsd"   condition="starts-with($TargetFrameworkMoniker, '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.') or $TargetFrameworkMoniker = ''" />
```

to

```
<Association extension="config" schema="%InstallRoot%/xml/schemas/%LCID%/dotNetConfig.xsd"   condition="starts-with($TargetFrameworkMoniker, '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.') or starts-with($TargetFrameworkMoniker, '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6')" />
```

Closed and reopened VS2013 and intellisense in both app.config and web.config files started to work again (with .NET 4.6 targeting projects).

Comment: For VS2017 Enterprise path of the catalog.xml is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas\catalog.xml

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 has the same problem with .NETFramework 4.7.  This solution, with an additional "or starts-with .... v4.7')"-clause, solves that problem. See @MeetingAttender's comment for the location of catalog.xml

Answer (score 13):

From the main menu in VS, choose **XML > Schemas...** (must have XML file open in IDE to see the **XML** menu item). In the window that pops up, find the entry for **DotNetConfig.xsd** (should be first item), and select the checkmark in the **Use** column for that entry. Then click OK.

Comment: `main menu`?! Are you talking about the `File` menu? The `Edit` menu...?  :s

Comment: @ScottFraley In the main menu bar there is an `XML` menu, alongside the `File` and `Edit` menus

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this solved it:

From the Visual Studio menu,
click *XML>Schemas...*

Look for *DotNetConfig.xsd*

Make sure you check *'use this schema'*

And *'Ok'*