# Can't remove RazorCustomSchema.xsd on VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xsd, app-config

I want to get rid of schema warnings on my project. Here are the warnings:

- Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.

So, I made a research and find this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355278/visual-studio-always-selects-the-wrong-xsd-for-app-config/4400071#4400071). However, I realised that RazorCustomSchema.xsd is selected and although I select "Don't use this schema" and click OK, RazorCustomSchema came selected again. I want to select DotNetConfig40.xsd but I can't. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem isn't to do with the Razor schema. The problem is explained and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400071/419