# App.config cause "Could not find schema information for the element 'supportRuntime'"

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite

I try to use SQLite dll, everything go fine. I have a little problem about SQLite.dll is v2.xx can't use with my project .NET v4.

So I found the solution in this website that create App.config, with the information like this

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
 </startup>
```

So, the solution work. I can use SQLite properly, but the compiler always show message like this

[image: Problem]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Select the schema for `app.config` properties as `DotNetConfig35.xsd`.

Open app.config file, right click on it and go to properties, you can see the schema attribute over there.

Comment: Yeah i got the same issue. To resolve that you need to update `DotNetConfig` files as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400071/632337).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also and tried a few ideas I found online such as creating schema from app.config etc but not fully resolving my issue as for some reason my program kept using DotNetConfig.xsd rather then the new App.xsd I just created. Even when I told it to use App.xsd and not DotNetConfig.xsd, it would override and use both causing a WARNING due to clash of names used.

So I decided to look at DotNetConfig.xsd directly and found that it doesn't contain `<supportedRuntime>` hence why it can't find it. Instead it does have `<runtime>`.

Use this one instead in your App.config and all solved.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017 after loading in many of the extra add-ins, they will add new XSD schema automatically. You can restore proper behavior by clicking on the Schemas line below and specifying which ones to use.

[image]

If you delete the ones you don't want and select the dotnet.xsd, rebuilding the project puts the other ones back in below the dotnet.xsd, this allows recompiles to work. Notice in image below it's at the top of the list.

[image]