# After Update of Windows 10 schema references lost

Tags: wpf, windows

This is really annoying: a WPF production application that works for months at the customer and hasn't been touched suddenly stopped to compile. I'm getting tons of errors of the type "schema information not found":

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation:Grid'
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation:UserControl'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation:Grid.ColumnDefinitions'.
etc...
```

Anyone out there that has an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry @halfer, for obvious reasons I was not able to properly express all the warm happiness I felt in the moment when I wrote the text. How can I remove the word "urgent" (which I can't find in my text) or change the wording?

Comment: You can change the text [using the edit function](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44043503/edit), I have done it for you. You can see the [revision history here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44043503/revisions).

Comment: Done. Hopefully now all obstacles are removed and someone can help me.

Comment: Probably not. I don't code for this platform, but my guess would be that without any information about your application - maybe some code? - people will struggle to work out what the problem is. I'm happy to be wrong on that matter, but readers tend to ignore brief questions here simply because 99% of them are not solvable until more information is given. What more information could you supply?

Comment: Have you [researched the problem as well](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Could+not+find+schema+information+for+the+element+wpf)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016719/app-config-cause-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-element-supportrunt

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a day of playing around I got the thing working again and I would like to share what happened.

All the errors came from a single user control. They were so many that their count exceeded what VS2015 would display. When I opened the component in the editor I could see the XAML code but the design window didn't show up, as if for VS this was a normal class module.

After trying around eventually I copied both file of the component (XAML and c#) to a backup location, deleted the coponent from the project, created a new user control with the same name and copied and pasted all code from the saved files into the newly created component. And suddenly everything worked again as always.

It seems to me that the problem was somewhere within VS2015 as the application works now again with literally the same code as before. I only recently updated from VS2013 and in all the years I never had any comparable issue with that version.