# VS2010: Adding settings to settings.settings causes app.config schema errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, app-config

Adding a **setting** to `Settings.settings`:

[image]

causes Visual Studio 2010 to *create* an `app.config` file, and *mirror* the settings in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    [...snip...]
    <userSettings>
        <ContosoManagementSystem.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="foo" serializeAs="String">
                <value>bar</value>
            </setting>
        </ContosoManagementSystem.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

But when Visual Studio does this, Visual Studio complains that Visual Studio doesn't know what Visual Studio did:

> Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'.

What gives?

---

Note the [similar question that doesn't apply to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229155/app-config-configsections-custom-settings-can-not-find-schema-information):

- Visual Studio 2010 vs Visual Studio 2008
- accepted answer doesn't work

---

There some suggestions to alter the *schemas* used by `app.config`:

[image]

Visual Studio default schema to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd`

i've tried changing it to other schemas:

- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig30.xsd"`

  causes VS to choke on `DotNetConfig30` itself (*The complexType 'configSection_section' has already been declared.*)
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig30.xsd"`

  causes VS to choke on `DotNetConfig30` itself (*The complexType 'configSection_section' has already been declared.*)
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig20.xsd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig30.xsd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig35.xsd"`

  causes VS to choke on `DotNetConfig30` itself (*The complexType 'configSection_section' has already been declared.*)

How do i make Visual Studio 2010 not give errors as a result of something Visual Studio 2010 did when i editing something in Visual Studio 2010.

Ian Boyd [is getting aggravated](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEyaxm26YBI).